# TCL: When click the "x" button show: invoked break outside of a loop

Tags: tcl

I want to use bgerror to show the error information, an example:

```
entry .e -textvariable name
button .b -text check -command [list CheckName]
grid .e
grid .b

proc CheckName {} {
   global name
   if {$name>0} {
       ....
   } else {
       bgerror "Please Input the name!"
   }
}
```

For the error window, if i click the "OK" button, that's ok, but if i click the "x" button, there will show another message "invoked break outside of a loop", how to solve this problem? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bgerror` callback is not just a standard procedure, as it interacts with the event loop specially. In particular, if it gives a `break` condition, it triggers the draining of any queued errors. It also reads from the `errorInfo` global variable to get the current stack trace.

The easiest way to use it in approximately the way you want  is to inject the error into the event loop as the result of processing an event. Here is a simple way to do this:

```
after idle [list error "this is an error message"]
```